# I keep getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable and I am not sure how to fix it

Tags: python, string, helper

This is the code I have written and it should tell me the radius of the circle after but instead I keep getting an error.

````
PI = 3.141593
radius_p = float(input('radius'))
perimeter = 2 * PI * radius_p
print('perimeter: ') + str(perimeter)
# Ask the user for the radius of the room
# Calculate the perimeter
# Print the perimeter

this is what I get after 

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-ba1678e7ffca> in <module>()
      2 radius_p = float(input('radius'))
      3 perimeter = 2 * PI * radius_p
----> 4 print('perimeter: ') + str(perimeter)
      5 # Ask the user for the radius of the room
      6 # Calculate the perimeter

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
````

Comment: `print('perimeter: ' + str(perimeter))`

Comment: @SeanHsieh I changed it to that and still go the same error

Comment: I guess the problem is you used `str` as a variable name somewhere in the code. Dont use built-in names as variable names.

Comment: Then how come you have same error since the answer you accepted works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `print()` function prints a value to the shell or the console without returning anything. This is why when you are concatenating `print()` which returns `NoneType` with a `str()` function which is in string format, it results in an error. Python doesn't allow concat operation with variables of different types. This is what you should correct your code to.

```
PI = 3.141593
radius_p = float(input('radius'))
perimeter = 2 * PI * radius_p
print('perimeter:', str(perimeter))
```

You should get an output like the one I did below by entering 4.
[image]

**Note:** If the problem persists then you need to share the full code with us because **you might be using the str object as a variable name** somewhere which is incorrect.

Comment: thank you this worked. for some reason it wasn't working in the program i was using

Answer (score 0):

Syntax at print statement line is wrong. It should be

> print('perimeter: ' + str(perimeter))

If you are still getting error, just for checking assign string value of perimeter to another variable and print

> newperi = str(perimeter)

> print('perimeter: ' + newperi)